# clang plugin compilation error: undefined symbols llvm::Registry<clang::PluginASTAction, llvm::RegistryTraits<clang::PluginASTAction> >

Tags: macos, plugins, clang, llvm

I'm trying to build [llvm clang samples](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples). 
Everything works fine except the `plugin_print_funcnames.cpp` plugin compilation. The code is found here: [plugin_print_funcnames.cpp](https://github.com/eliben/llvm-clang-samples/blob/master/src_clang/plugin_print_funcnames.cpp)

It seems like that the clang++ cannot find the library `llvm:Registry<>` is not in the llvm library. 
I use llvm/clang from brew with the command `brew install llvm`.

What might be wrong?

This is a command line:

```
g++ -fpic -fno-rtti -O0 -g `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD/bin/llvm-config --cxxflags` -I$HOME/llvm/from_git/llvm/tools/clang/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD/tools/clang/include src_clang/plugin_print_funcnames.cpp \
        -shared `/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/HEAD/bin/llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs` -o build/plugin_print_funcnames.so
```

These are part of error messages:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "llvm::Registry<clang::PluginASTAction, llvm::RegistryTraits<clang::PluginASTAction> >::ListenerHead", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__I_a in plugin_print_funcnames-342dff.o
  "llvm::Registry<clang::PluginASTAction, llvm::RegistryTraits<clang::PluginASTAction> >::Head", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure you're long since past needing this, but I ran into a similar problem.  Here's the answer to your specific question as well as the command I use to figure out the answer.  Go into the llvm/clang lib directory and type:

```
$ nm -o *.a |grep Registry |grep PluginASTAction |cut -d ':' -f 1 |uniq
libclangFrontend.a
libclangFrontendTool.a
```

The `-o` flag to `nm` is very important because it tells nm to print the filename on every line, so you have context when grep finds a match.

You add the appropriate library to your link line after you find it using the technique in the answer. Then, if you get another linker error, you repeat the process. Eventually the last one goes away. For instance, in the above case, you'd add -lclangFrontend -lclangFrontendTool.

For me, it was a process of about 10 different libraries I had to find like this.

I believe the list of things I had to add was: `-lclangSerialization -lclangASTMatchers -lclangSema -lclangAnalysis -lclangRewriteFrontend -lclangEdit -lclangParse -lclangFrontend -lclangBasic -lclangDriver -lclangAST -lclangLex`  but that was in addition to the ones from running `llvm/bin/llvm-config --ldflags --libs --system-libs`.   This was on latest OS X at the time of writing.

Comment: Could you elaborate how to remove the error message?